# Make circular div expand to fill the entire page when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a circular div in the middle of my page and I want to make it expand to the full size of the screen when clicked. Any suggestions?

I would like it to transition smoothly if possible.

Comment: please post your code HTML/CSS and a fiddle would be even better: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Onclick animate the width and height. What's the big mystery?

Comment: Yeah, pretty easy with jQuery!

Comment: Do you want the circle to expand as a circle until it reaches the first constraining edge (top/bottom, or left/right), or do you want a visual effect similar to an iris transition where the circle grows and replaces the previous background entirely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You can with css and javascript

```
div.small {
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.big {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

JS (i'm using zepto, but jquery is the same)

```
$(window).on("click", ".small", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).addClass("big"); }, 1 );
});

$(window).on("click", ".big", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).removeClass("big"); }, 1 );
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="small"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/Vc492/

---

## without javascript

CSS

```
label {
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

input:checked + label {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #0f0;
}

input {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="hidden-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
<label for="hidden-checkbox"></label>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/85qfu/

Comment: I would like to do this without holding the click on the mouse. This is exactly what I want though!

Comment: added the js, please check out the original answer

Comment: @user3508874 thanks for doing it at the same time. you will notice that using css animations is way more performant than using jquery animations.

Comment: ok, added the version without javascript... couldn't resist!

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps you could mark this as the accepted answer, or ask me more help if there's something still not fitting your needs.